# Setting up Postgres sql with Django

Tags: python, sql, django, database, postgresql

I am new to Django and Python, I know my way around Postgres. Is it possible to create tables and set many to many connections in Postgres and make it reflect in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the inspectdb management command.

Django comes with a utility called inspectdb that can create models by introspecting an existing database:

1. Create your tables and relations in Postgres
2. Setup your DATABASES in settings.py
3. Run `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models

Answer (score 0):

Yes. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Follow the directions here. You must create an intermediary table to handle the relationships.